How much variation in the transimpedance gain of the TIA is acceptable?
I have designed a transimpedance amplifier with a transimpedance gain that varies from 113.1dB to 111.46dB over a current input range from 200nA to 6uA. Is this variation in transimpedance gain acceptable?
I know the answer depends on my application, but what I want to know is:

Whether the variation in the trans-impedance gain is a normal problem while designing a TIA and whether one is always aiming to get a really precise trans-impedance gain?
Or, in general, people can't get a precise trans-impedance gain and one can live with a variation unless and until it is a really big variation and creates a big problem with his application?

I will appreciate any help in understanding this.
Thanks and Regards,

Is such massive TIA gain used in FB?

Presumably this is open loop gain?

Is this an op-amp based TIA or an on-chip design (from the transistors up)? Or ...?

Hi, I made the TIA using a negative feedback with a Resistor using a voltage amplifier(opamp). The op-amp voltage amplifier was made using a single differential pair with single output .

A variation between 113.1dB and 111.46dB is 1.64dB, or 20% change in gain.
Depending on what you want to use this TIA for, that's either very bad, or not a problem.
If you want to use it to make precision current measurements, then 20% change of gain is probably far too much non-linearity. Your figures have shown that the precision range is smaller than 0.2u to 6u, which is not a big range already, not much more than a decade.
If you want to use it to get digital data from a opto-receiver diode, then it's probably just fine.

Variation in gain is always a potential problem when designing any sort of amplifier. A fed-back amplifier relies on having a very high gain active amplifier, whose closed-loop gain is controlled by passive feedback elements, which works well until the 'very high gain' gets reduced either near to the rails, or at high frequencies. This ought to be 'very good' in its working range, and quickly gets very bad at the limits of its range. An open loop amplifier will tend to have more error within its range, but get bad less quickly at the limits of its range.

If you are seeing 20% change in gain, then that might be reasonable for an open loop amplifier. If it's a fed-back amplifier, then it's probably hitting the rails. Back off the range a bit.

In most applications, people will engineer an amplifier that's only a bit better than they need, rather than wasting money and design time making something that's much better. So, look to your requirements, how accurate do you need, how accurate can you afford?


Have you thought about compression? i.e. your output signal is so large your Op-Amp has started to compress because of lack of headroom at the output?
If that's the case, then you have to decide dor yourself whether that's good enough or not.
